# if statement appears broken

Tags: objective-c, logic

Something is wrong, this code

```
if ([g count] >= 1) {
     NSLog(@"%@", [g objectAtIndex:1]);
}
```

Keeps generating this error

```
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Unless I'm going crazy, this shouldn't happen, right?

The code is NOT multithreaded at this point and I'm working off a simple array. If I NSLog the g.count, i get a value of 1.

EDIT: I have also tried

```
if ([g count] > 0) {
     NSLog(@"%@", [g objectAtIndex:1]);
}
```

and get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `count` is 1, it means that you can use index zero. Index of `1` is not valid.

In general, only indexes from zero to `count-1`, inclusive, are valid.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something stupid on my part. Sometimes the simple things elude me. I will accept your answer in 11 minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 3):

If the count of the array == 1 then it only has index 0 right?

The correct code would be

```
if ([g count] >= 2) {
     NSLog(@"%@", [g objectAtIndex:1]);
}
```

or

```
if ([g count] >= 1) {
     NSLog(@"%@", [g objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```

Depending what index you need.

Comment: Thank you, while you are correct dasblinkenlight beat you to it. I will still up vote you though.